# Google Sheets scripts to add rows based on a cell value

Tags: google-apps-script

can someone please help me with the script

I want to add 9 rows after the first row, 4 rows after the second row basically adding rows based on the Column D value mentioned in the screenshot

[image]

Comment: Please read "[ask]" and the linked pages. Screenshots are never appropriate for describing the primary problem as we can't reuse data, can't search it... "[Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/128421)"
"[Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812)"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Adding rows**

The key to situations where your adding or removing rows is to use a counter to keep track of the changing number of rows.  By using `getDataRange()` the index `i` is normally one less than the row number until it begins to add rows so the add counter `a` bridges the gap between the index of fixed 2d array v and the rows that are added between the old rows which we're read to assemble the 2d array v in the `rg.getValues()` line.

```
function addingRows() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getActiveSheet();
  var rg=sh.getDataRange();
  var v=rg.getValues();
  var a=0;
  //r[3] is column 4
  //The forEach is appropriate here since we know we have to iterate through the entire array with no need for breaking out
  v.forEach(function(r,i){
    if(r[3]>0) {
      sh.insertRowsAfter(i+1+a,r[3]);//i+1+a is the row number
      a+=r[3];//increased by the number of rows which were just added
    }
  });
}
```

[Sheet.insertRowsAfter](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#insertRowsAfter(Integer,Integer))

Animation:

[image]

Comment: Please don't just toss out code, explain how it works and why it's the appropriate solution. We want to educate, not just answer the immediate question.